# flutter doctor -v : Failed to download windows-x64 tools

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

My `Flutter device daemon`cannot be started. My `flutter pub get`returns:

```
Package not found 
(Unauthorized access) error 69
```

I checked and I am positive there is nothing wrong with my **internet connection**

I used `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter upgrade --force`
which lead me here. Now I have a download problem.
My `Flutter doctor -v`Log:

```
Downloading package sky_engine...                                1,258ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                         1,653ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                 1,459ms
Downloading windows-x64 tools...                                   284ms
Downloading windows-x64 tools...                                   557ms
Failed to download
https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/3f3e560236539b7e2702f5ac790b2a4691b32d4
9/windows-x64/artifacts.zip. Ensure you have network connectivity and then try again.
Exception: 403

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      ArtifactUpdater._downloadArchive (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:1113:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      EngineCachedArtifact.updateInner (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:946:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      CachedArtifact.update (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:848:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Cache.updateAll (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:715:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1629:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1367:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

As The error above says, it can not download windows_64x tools stored in the link
"https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/3f3e560236539b7e2702f5ac790b2a4691b32d49/windows-x64/artifacts.zip"

**But I can download it fine manually!**

I did everything I could think of would love any solutions or suggestions. Thanks in advance.